# How do I prepare a async generator function as argument of an other function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

How do I prepare a async generator function as argument of an other function?

When I use loop.run_in_executor to wrap a ordinary function as async task, one of its parameter is a generator (`data` of`requests.post`)

```py
import asyncio, os, sys, subprocess, aionotify, tempfile

class CommandDelegate():
    def _yielding_log(self, pid, stdout_file):
        w = aionotify.Watcher()
        w.setup(loop)
        if type(stdout_file) not in [str, bytes]:
            stdout_file = stdout_file.name
        try:
            w.watch(stdout_file, aionotify.Flags.MODIFY | aionotify.Flags.CLOSE_WRITE)
            with open(stdout_file, 'r') as the_file:
                while True:
                    line = the_file.readline()
                    if line != '':
                        yield line
                    else:
                        if os.path.exists('/proc/' + pid):
                            break
                        evt = w.get_event()
                        parsed_flags = aionotify.Flags.parse(evt.flags)
                        if aionotify.Flags.MODIFY in parsed_flags:
                            continue
                        if aionotify.Flags.CLOSE_WRITE in parsed_flags:
                            break
        finally:
            w.close()


    def _exec_command(self, job_dir, order, shell_command):
        stdout_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='stdout', suffix='log', delete=False)
        cmd = shlex.split(shell_command)
        ps = subprocess.Popen(args=cmd, stdout=stdout_file, cwd=job_dir, stderr=stdout_file)
##### WHAT TO DO HERE
        loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.post, 'upstream', data=
                             WHAT__TO__DO__HERE(self._yielding_log(stdout_file))
                             )
        return ps.wait() != 0
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you wan to log `stdout` and `stderr` on a file ? (and watch it with `aionotify` ?). In the end, you want to run the command and get it's whole output before posting it to upstream ? If you really want to use `asyncio` in order to create the subprocess, see [asyncio.loop.subprocess_exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.subprocess_exec) method. Otherwise, just use `Popen`, wait until it finish, and post the output ; no need to be notified of changes on the output log file (but maybe I misunderstood the problem)

Comment: Ok, let me put it clear, the foremost `while true read` is for catching up the output, and when encountered eof (in case read empty str, lean on inotify). The key point here is the case  when subprocess last long time.  Could you please give an example on `asyncio.loop.subprocess_exec` for this job?

Comment: You aren't even using asyncio except to call `run_in_executor`. Confusingly, `_yielding_log` isn't async at all, it's an ordinary generator. The `loop` variable appears undefined. Can you trim your code to the barest minimum that still demonstrates the issue, and that we can _run_ in order to see where the problem lies?